# Integral over Dirac Delta function with constants in it

Tags: integration, dirac-delta

I have a question about an integral I have to solve. The question is: compute the following integral:
$$\nu=\int \frac{dk}{(2 \pi)^3} \delta(\epsilon + E_F -E(k)) $$

express it in terms of $v_F$, $k_F$.

And given is also:
We can approximate the energy by $E(k)-E_F=\hbar v_F (\delta k)$, $(\delta k) = |k|-k_F << k_F$.

So I evaluated this integral and got the answer $$ \frac{2}{(2 \pi)^3 |\hbar v_F|} $$

But this answer does not depend on $k_F$, so I am assuming that I did something wromg. I searched the whole internet for the answer, but couldn't find it..

Can somebody please help me?

Comment: "I searched the whole internet for the answer" How would you do that?